# Intercepting information being sent over an unencrypted channel

Tags: http

User credentials are being sent over an unencrypted http connection on a website. How can a third party read the user credentials by intercepting an unencrypted HTTP connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an somewhat long answer on the Information Security board [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54313/intercepting-wifi-traffic).  The short answer is that if the third party can read the unencrypted network packets then it is a simple matter to scan for packets containing passwords being sent to banks, shopping sites, Facebook, etc.  You can get the packets by:

- Listening to WiFi radio signals OR
- Setting up a WiFi access point and tricking people/victims to use it OR
- Getting physical access to networking hardware like a switch or a router.